# Job_Queue en py-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, queue

Estoy creando un programa con py-telegram-bot en donde se requiere que varios usuarios puedan perdirle informacion a la vez o no.

```
def procesarticket(context):
    try:
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver.get("página")
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        #resto del código
        recibecomandos = True
        context.job.context['RecibeComandos'] = recibecomandos
        return ESPERAORDENES
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Se produjo una excepción: {e}")
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=context.job.context["ID"], text="Se produjo un error inesperado. Contacte con soporte.")
        return ESPERAERROR

def confirmaelticket(update, context):   
    respuesta = update.message.text.lower()
    if respuesta == "si":
        mensaje_a_supervisores = f'El técnico {context.user_data["Tecnico"]} inició con el ticket: {context.user_data["Ticket"]}.'
        enviar_mensaje_a_supervisores(context, mensaje_a_supervisores)
        context.user_data["TicketEnCurso"] = True
        update.message.reply_text(f"Perfecto. Estoy buscando la información de su ticket. Espere unos segundos.")
        context.job_queue.run_once(procesarticket, 0, context=context.user_data)
    elif respuesta == "no":
        update.message.reply_text("Inserte el número de ticket.")
        return INDICATICKET
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Por favor, ingrese Si o No.")
```

La parte del programa lo hace a la perfeccion. Pero cuando termina y tiene que ir a return ESPERAORDENES, ESPERAERROR, INDICATICKET o INDICANODO no lo hace, vuelve a confirma el ticket y si el usuario manda un texto el programa responde con:

else:
update.message.reply_text("Por favor, ingrese Si o No.")

Necesitaria que siga los return que estan en procesarticket(context)